# Настройки конфигурации PHP

Tags: php, config

Подскажите где можно настроить вот это:

```
./configure \
--with-config-file-path=/usr/local/apache2/conf \
--with-jpeg-dir \
--with-png-dir \
--with-vpx-dir \
--with-freetype-dir \
--enable-apc \
--enable-bcmath \
--enable-calendar \
--enable-dba \
--enable-exif \
--enable-ftp \
--enable-mbstring \
--enable-shmop \
--enable-sigchild \
--enable-soap \
--enable-sockets \
--enable-sysvmsg \
--enable-zip \
--enable-gd-native-ttf  \
--with-gd \
--with-apxs2=/usr/local/httpd/bin/apxs \
--with-bz2 \
--with-curl \
--with-gettext \
--with-mcrypt \
--with-mysql-sock=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock \
--with-openssl \
--with-pdo-mysql \
--with-xmlrpc \
--with-zlib
```

Это какой то файл? или это выставляется через SSH. Как я могу сменить эту конфигурацию?

Comment: Это параметры компиляции. Сменить - никак, только скомпилировать заново. Забейте.

Comment: забить нельзя, у меня в GD нету поддержки jpg изображений. 
Вот вроде как решение http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167860/compiling-php-with-gd-and-libjpeg-support но я не пойму как его реализовать

Comment: Скачиваете [исходники](http://php.net/git.php) и собираете из них php, когда будете вызывать `./configure`, тогда укажете все эти параметры

Comment: @BOPOH оформите как ответ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему решил. У меня на VPS стоит centos-webpanel . И как оказалось там очень просто это делать. 
PHP Settings->PHP Version Switcher->Выбираем версию пхп -> Next ->Видим то что на скрине ->Меняем параметры (В моем случае я добавил поддержку Jpg в GD)->Start Compiler in Background -> Готово[image: скрин]